# Sails.js mongodb map reduce

Tags: mongodb, sails.js, waterline

I'm using sails with sails-mongo and I'm looking to perform an aggregation across a collection. I want to reuse the connection object that waterline uses, rather than create an entirely new connection to the mongodb server. Is this connection object available somewhere, and can it perform any query type?

This is predicated on the understanding that waterline/sails cannot currently do aggregations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you're looking for the `.native` method, which returns the raw node `mongo` collection instance.  This allows you to use native Mongo methods.  For example, if you a `User` model in Sails, you would do:

```
User.native(function(err, userCollection) {

    userCollection.aggregate(...)

}
```

Docs for the native Node Mongo driver are [here](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/), including a section on how to do aggregation.

Docs for the `.native` method are [on the sailsjs.org](http://sailsjs.org/#/documentation/reference/waterline/models/native.html).

Comment: Where do you find this information? Apart from reading the sails-mongo source and specifically looking for it I couldn't find any reference to the `native` method

Answer (score 1):

Just for less searching and to share experience, here is a working template for mongodb aggregation in Sails.js (for model User) :

```
User.native(function(err, collection) {
    if (err) return res.serverError(err);

    collection.aggregate(
      [
        //Your matching and grouping here
        //{ $match : { country : user.country } },
        //{ $group: { _id: "$age", count: { $sum: 1 } } }
      ], function(err, result){
           if (err) return res.serverError(err);
           console.log(result);
         }
    );
});
```

More about aggreagation: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/aggregation-with-user-preference-data/

Comment: there is a missing **}** in your code, the final should look like this: `});});`

Comment: glad to help :D